# Abuse of editing privileges?

Tags: discussion, edits

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877814/editing-ionic-tab-icon-styles), and noticed that the code on the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877814/editing-ionic-tab-icon-styles/36878889#36878889) answer had some broken code in it. It appears that after the answered was posted [someone edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36878889/revisions) and spammed spaces in parts of the css that made it invalid. I don't know whether this was done on purpose or not, but I did not know what to do in the case. Should this user be reported? Should the edit be rolled back?

Comment: Roll back the edit, if it happens again flag the post for moderator attention with a custom flag explaining what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like that user used some kind of "auto formatting" without checking if the result is still valid.

Comment: I doubt this was an abuse. It's more likely that his computer did that automatically and he didn't notice. Roll it back, but let's not assume bad intentions here.

Comment: @animuson ok cool, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: "... I don't know whether this was done on purpose or not...". Generally it is not useful to think some damage was done on purpose. This case it  obviously is was not. Also: it is way far from "Abuse"

Comment: @g.pickardou: There's no "obviously" about this, and if this were indeed found to be vandalism then, yes, that's abuse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. You are right in both of your statements. 1) Using "obviously" was not right. I should phrase "regarding this particular case there is a very high probability it was not done on purpose". 2) We must prevent vandalism, agree. Vandalism is destructive. My point was: It is not useful to suppose abuse in a particular case were there is many much more possible explanation. Doing such a thing also could be destructive both for self both for others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That edit should be rolled back by someone with the ability to do that as it not only makes edits to the code but the changes will cause it to break as there should be no spaces in the names.

I would also think that the user should have their edit history reviewed to ensure there are no other really bad edits that need dealt with.

Comment: Roll back bad code to bad code, that will make it better!  Nonsense.

Comment: @HansPassant So you would not suggest rolling back an edit that breaks code if the original code is not good? The code may not do what it is supposed to but in the case of this edit it will be impossible for it to work. Wouldn't you always want to have code that could work even if it won't work as excepted?

Comment: @HansPassant:  If there is bad code in a question it should be the OP's, not an editor's.

Comment: @JoeW Look at that guys freaking history, he really seems to love randomly adding spaces without any knowledge of the impact that his change can/will have.

Comment: It was definitely a bad edit and should be rolled back. It looks like the guy is using a simple formatting tool for programming languages... but it obviously doesn't know css.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that he's using some auto formatting tool. It's treating dashes as the binary subtraction operator, the `100e` as a numeric value with the `m` not part of it. Honestly, use of such a tool is unwelcome IMHO. Looking at some of the other auto formats he's done, he's reformatting code that's perfectly fine to fit his own standards and I'll be damned if I let him make such edits to my posts.

Comment: Has anyone with the appropriate privileges/tools alerted this guy to what his formatting tool is doing so that he stops?

Comment: And why is he not using his _eyes_ to _look at the post_ before submitting it? You can't blame your tools for this level of incompetence.